# Strimzi topic operator not working - Openshift

Tags: apache-kafka, openshift, apache-zookeeper, strimzi

I deployed Strimzi topic operator on openshift using the following documentation: https://strimzi.io/docs/0.12.2/full.html#deploying-the-topic-operator-standalone-deploying. This does not work and error shown below:

```
2020-02-26 13:40:30 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib`enter code here`
2020-02-26 13:40:30 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2020-02-26 13:40:30 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2020-02-26 13:40:30 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:os.name=Linux
2020-02-26 13:40:30 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:os.arch=amd64
2020-02-26 13:40:30 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:os.version=3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64
2020-02-26 13:40:30 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:user.name=?
2020-02-26 13:40:30 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:user.home=?
2020-02-26 13:40:30 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:user.dir=/opt/strimzi
2020-02-26 13:40:30 INFO  ZooKeeper:442 - Initiating client connection, connectString=172.30.93.216:2181 sessionTimeout=500000 watcher=org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient@74e374fc
2020-02-26 13:40:31 INFO  ZkClient:936 - Waiting for keeper state SyncConnected
2020-02-26 13:40:31 INFO  ClientCnxn:1025 - Opening socket connection to server soumo-zookeeper-client.kube-system.svc.cluster.local/172.30.93.216:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)

    2020-02-26 13:40:31 INFO  ClientCnxn:879 - Socket connection established to soumo-zookeeper-client.kube-system.svc.cluster.local/172.30.93.216:2181, initiating session
2020-02-26 13:40:31 WARN  ClientCnxn:1164 - Session 0x0 for server soumo-zookeeper-client.kube-system.svc.cluster.local/172.30.93.216:2181, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:377) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:68) ~[org.apache.zookeeper.zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-4c25d480e66aadd371de8bd2fd8da255ac140bcf]
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:366) ~[org.apache.zookeeper.zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-4c25d480e66aadd371de8bd2fd8da255ac140bcf]
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141) [org.apache.zookeeper.zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-4c25d480e66aadd371de8bd2fd8da255ac140bcf]
2020-02-26 13:40:34 INFO  ClientCnxn:1025 - Opening socket connection to server soumo-zookeeper-client.kube-system.svc.cluster.local/172.30.93.216:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2020-02-26 13:40:34 INFO  ClientCnxn:879 - Socket connection established to soumo-zookeeper-client.kube-system.svc.cluster.local/172.30.93.216:2181, initiating session
2020-02-26 13:40:34 WARN  ClientCnxn:1164 - Session 0x0 for server soumo-zookeeper-client.kube-system.svc.cluster.local/172.30.93.216:2181, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: How about trying the latest stable version

Comment: using the latest stable release - https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator/releases/tag/0.16.2

Comment: Your docs link is not. That's what I meant

Comment: In any case, it would be great if you could show your service definitions

Comment: soumo-kafka-bootstrap    ClusterIP      172.30.194.198   <none>                        9091/TCP,9092/TCP,9093/TCP   7d
soumo-kafka-brokers      ClusterIP      None             <none>                        9091/TCP,9092/TCP,9093/TCP   7d
soumo-zookeeper-client   ClusterIP      172.30.93.216    <none>                        2181/TCP                     7d
soumo-zookeeper-nodes    ClusterIP      None             <none>                        2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP   7d

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your YAML files